# Pitch / Note detection using Aubio or PyAudio

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, pitch, aubio

**Problem**: I am trying to write some code in python which will detect the pitch/note of the live feed from the microphone. So basically I will be playing a note on my guitar and my code has to check and tell me which note it is.

**Research**: I have searched for multiple libraries to do this and the best one I could find were Aubio and PyAudio. So any help doing this will be appreciated.

**NOTE**- I don't want it in an array. I just want it like.

```
if note == 'A':
   keyboard.press_and_release('w')
```

Any help for this ??

Answer (score 1):

pyaudio actually has a [demo](https://github.com/aubio/aubio/blob/master/python/demos/demo_pyaudio.py) that converts microphone audio into a stream of numbers that correspond to unnamed notes. From there, you can convert the numbers to int, tune the numbers to notes and use that as your note detection.